# Pascal DLL in C++ aplication on ARM platform

Tags: c++, linux, arm, pascal

I have a huge amount of code written in Pascal and I need to use it in a C++ application running on an embedded PC with ARM9 processor. My idea was cross compiling Pascal code to dll libraries which I wanted to include in my C++ app. I tried to install Lazarus but I can't get work its cross compiler and I tried to install compiler directly to the embedded PC with similar result. C++ cross compiler works perfectly. Is there any way how to get Pascal code working in C++ application on different platform? I will provide any additional info if needed.

**Additional info:**

- the embedded pc is for use in extremely low temperatures so it has low ram (32MB) running a trimmed Linux and there is only a little free space left on its flash memory (i have to use the SD card for all files)

Comment: Perhaps you might consider using the [P2C](http://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/p2c/) Pascal to C translator?

Comment: Be more clear about what goes wrong with the crosscompiler. What kind of target is it (oabi, eabi?)

Comment: I managed to compile application on both PC and device but all attempts end with "illegal instruction" error when I try to run it. I gave up. Even if I somehow get it work, there will be more problems with data types (as Mats mentioned) and bunch of other things. In the end it's actually faster to rewrite code from Pascal to C++ then try to make these two languages work together. Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anyone can conclusively answer your question, but some hints:

1. You will need to find a way to communicate between the C++ and Pascal code. This may simply be a case of defining any interface function as a C or C++ style function. But for example strings in Pascal are often NOT standard C or C++ style strings, so will need some extra handling to work out right. Structs (RECORD in pascal) and classes will require even more careful handling as to how they interface between the C++ and Pascal code - in most cases, it will become a full marshalling solution (that is, convert to a byte-stream, and then convert back to correct type at the other end).
2. Cross compilation of the Pascal code relies on having a Pascal compiler that matches your Pascal code AND your target. If you can't compile your code to the correct target, all other parts of the project will fail... There is a "standard" for Pascal, but most compilers have a range of extensions.
3. Have you considered making the Pascal code a standalone application that produces results as a file, rather than directly interfacing to the C++ code? Reading a file that you can control the format of can be a much easier solution than trying to interface one language to another.